# OkHttp, is the automatic GZIP disabled when using a custom interceptor?

Tags: android, gzip, okhttp

I am using OkHttp 2.3.0 in my Android app. My question is about the transparent GZIP feature. According to the documentation, it should be silently there. But I cannot see the `("accept-encoding", "gzip")` header in the request.

I am using a custom interceptor to add authentication:

```
@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();

    // 1. sign this request

    [get token]

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(token)) {
        // we have a token. let's use it to sign the request
        request = request.newBuilder()
                .header(AUTH_HEADER_KEY, BEARER_HEADER_VALUE + token)
                .build();
    }

    // 2. proceed with the request
    Log.d("t", "Headers " + request.headers()); <--- no gzip header here
    Response response = chain.proceed(request);
```

The log statement only shows the header I have added:

```
Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

but nothing about GZIP encoding. Should I do something else, or maybe the header is added after I invoke `chain.proceed(request)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header is added after `chain.proceed()`. You can see it by using a network interceptor instead of an application interceptor; see the OkHttp interceptors doc for a comparison of the two.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to log any OkHttp transparent headers from the app itself. Some people recommend using Charles proxy client, which is probably good way to analyze network traffic, although I found it tricky to make proper configuration, and from version 4 it's not a free tool anymore.
For my purpose though, I found it very useful to use [network profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/network-profiler), built into Android Studio (tested on Arctic Fox 2020.3.1).

You may see from below example, that `Accept-Encoding` header is available in request, - this header has been added automatically, I have not added it in my app.

[image]